# fetching random json getting first undefined then result

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, console, use-effect

Beginner on reactjs here, trying to fetch random json, getting the result i want to get, but not the way i want it, for some reason it prints first 'undefined' then after that the result. Why cant i get just the result and without this '?'
my code:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setThumbnail(json);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(thumbnail[0]?.thumbnailUrl);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Build</h1>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

console.log() inside App() directly will use the initial state of. thumbnail which is the empty, so it will show undefined.

To check the `thumbnail`, you should use another `useEffect` with adding a `thumbnail` dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (thumbnail.length > 0) {
    console.log(thumbnail[0].thumbnailUrl);
  }
}, [thumbnail]);
```

---

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState([]);
  const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setLoaded(true);
        setThumbnail(json);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoaded) {
      console.log(thumbnail[0]?.thumbnailUrl);
    }
  }, [thumbnail]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Build</h1>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: did that and still getting same result, how to have useeffect change initial state of thumbnail ? so that it is not empty ?

Comment: initial state can be empty, you can just check inside useEffect if it's empty or not by thumbnail.length !== 0

Comment: if i want to print that thumbnail for example inside <h1> it will always show first empty and then the result ? how to have just result and not empty ?

Comment: check thumbnail.length inside render by jsx. like <h1>{thumbnail.length === 0 ? 'empty' : thumbnail[0].thumbnailUrl}</h1>

Comment: As William said, in the first render the http call has not responded yet, so `thumbnail` is `[]`. React will always re-render your component when state changes...in your case when it receives data from the http call. Add a `loading` component with a new state `const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)` and then display your component according with its value: `{isLoading ? <Spinner> : <your-component>}`

Comment: @vpalmerini could you give working code with that example ?

Comment: @walee no problem

Comment: @William Wang this did not work for me and it is getting up voted ?

Comment: describe your question in detail.

Comment: @WilliamWang i dont want to get 'undefined' then after that result, i want to get just result without 'undefined'

Comment: as i informed above, you should check if thumbnail is empty or not, or as @vpalmerini suggested, add a new state which states isLoaded. i have updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

While the response of your `http` does not come, you can simply render a `loading` component (a text in this example), then when `thumbnail` state changes, React will re-render your component and update it with the new data.

Just a working example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [thumbnail, setThumbnail] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setThumbnail(json);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Build</h1>
      {isLoading ? (
        <h3>Loading...</h3>
      ) : (
        thumbnail.map((item) => {
          return <span key={item.id}>{item.title}</span>;
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: why this is not working :           return <span key={item.id}>{item[0].title}</span>;

Comment: Oh, `item` is an object, so you can not iterate over it. `thumbnail` is your array and `map()` maps each item of it, and those are objects with `id, title, etc`, got it? So it would be `<span key={item.id}>{item.title}</span>`, just as it is in the answer